# Store image with proxy_store, then process with lua

Tags: nginx, lua

I'm trying to accomplish something like this with nginx. First I use proxy_pass to download an image. Then I want to manipulate that image with lua and serve the manipulated image. I thought the easiest way to do this would be to use `proxy_store` to download the image to a file:

```
location ~* ^/test/(.*?)/(.*) {
    alias /some/path/$1_$2;
    proxy_pass http://$1/$2;
    proxy_store on;
    content_by_lua '
        -- use image at /some/path/$1_$2 here
    ';
}
```

And then read and manipulate that file with lua. However, this moves on to the `content_by_lua` section before the image has been downloaded and saved with `proxy_store`. How can I make the the image is downloaded before moving on to `content_by_lua`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out: I was looking for nginx subrequests. My new solution works something like this:

```
location ~* /proxy/(.*?)/(.*) {
  # download and return the image
  proxy_pass http://$1/$2;
}

location ~* ^/test/(.*?)/(.*) {
    # so we can use this url from lua
    set $url $1/$2;
    content_by_lua '
        -- grab the content of url using the /proxy route. This create a subrequest,
        -- which means it fits within nginx's async model.
        response = ngx.location.capture("/proxy/" .. ngx.var.url)
        -- response.body contains the image, do whatever you want with it
        resized = resize_image(response.body)
        -- finally, return the final image
        ngx.say(resized)
    ';
}
```